# Defining a getter that takes arguments in Dart

Tags: dart, getter

I would like to define a getter that can optionally take arguments. I managed to achieve that, however it only works if I put the obligatory `()` after the call. Here's the code:

```dart
get children => ([role=null]) {
  if(role == null || role == 'any') { return _children;               }
  else                              { return _children_by_role[role]; }
};
```

So now I can say

```dart
obj.children('something').length;
```

or

```dart
obj.children().length;
```

but I cannot say

```dart
obj.children; // this doesn't work
```

because it results in the following error:

```
Caught Closure call with mismatched arguments: function 'length' NoSuchMethodError : method not found: 'length' Receiver: Closure: ([dynamic])
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In Dart, getters are meant to be indistinguishable from accessing object properties, so it is illegal to define a getter that accepts an argument (even if it's optional).

Your getter takes no arguments, but with the `=>` operator, *returns* an anonymous function that takes an optional argument. So, `obj.children` is a function; therefore the statement `obj.children.length;` is an error because functions don't have the property `length`.

You may not be able to omit the parentheses, but your code would work more naturally if `get children` wasn't a getter function:

```dart
getChildren([roll]) { // null is the default value implicitly
  if (roll == null || roll == 'any') return _children;
  else return _children_by_roll[roll];
}
```

used as:

```dart
obj.getChildren().length;
```

or:

```dart
obj.getChildren(rollObject).length;
```

Comment: That's what I thought. Just wanted this to be a bit prettier than it is. Oh well :) Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Getters are not allowed to have any arguments.

You've managed to get around that by returning a closure instead but that mandates the () syntax (in which case it is not much better than a regular function).

If you are really determined to use the getter syntax you can get almost everything you want by using a combination of [function emulation](https://www.dartlang.org/articles/emulating-functions/) and delegation:

```dart
class ChildrenGetter {

  List _children;

  ChildrenGetter(this._children);

  // Function emulation: will be called whenever () is used on
  // a ChildrenGetter instance, e.g. childrenGetter();
  call([role = null]) {
    if(role == null || role == 'any') { return _children;               }
    // Omitted for scope of example, you should be able to 
    // modify to have this work
    //else                              { return _children_by_role[role]; }
  }

  // Delegate length
  get length => _children.length;

  // Delegate every other operator, method, getter, setter... 

}
```

And now your getter can be defined as:

```dart
get children => new ChildrenGetter(_children);
```

(In actual code you wouldn't want to return a new instance each time, but for the sake of the example, this was easiest.)

You can now call any of the following and receive proper results:

```dart
obj.children();
obj.children.length;        
obj.children('any').length;
```

Since you are returning a class that acts as a function when called with () but that can also have getters, setters, methods and operators that delegate to the actual children.

The one problem you will have is that `obj.children` will refer to the instance of `ChildrenGetter` and not to the delegated children.

I'm not sure I would recommend this approach, unless there is a good reason for it, but it's interesting to note that it can be done.

Comment: Indeed, it's a very interesting solution. I certainly don't need to overcomplicate my code with it, but it's nice to know how it can be done.

Answer (score 1):

Getters don't take arguments. You should just define a function with one or more default arguments to achieve what you want.